# View Logic Of PLC Controller

Tags: plc

Is it possible to extract the logic from a PLC to your computer so that the logic may be edited? and if so, how would I go about it?

I have little experience in the way of PLC's and would just like to tinker with the codes inside of existing ones.

Comment: Usually, yes, but it entirely depends on what model PLC that you have.

Comment: What kind of PLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can, most of the PLCs in the market have that 'uploading' feature. However there is a chance that the source files in that PLC are password protected by the programmer who programmed the PLC. You would need to know/guess the password for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install on the computer the programming software normally supplied by the PLC manufacturer that in many cases is a software that has to be purchased (not free). 
Also depending on the PLC you may need a specific connection cable, others instead can be connected via USB or Ethernet